# XML binding is not saving

Tags: c#, xml, wpf, xaml

I am currently working on a pretty simple `TreeView` WPF. I have a relatively simple XML file that I would like to be able to view and edit through this window. However I am having trouble getting the files to save.

My simplified XAML file looks like this

```
<Window x:Class="TreeView2.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Window.Resources>
        <XmlDataProvider x:Name="ListName" x:Key="MyList" 
                         Source="C:\CAD.Services\MASTER.xml"  
                         XPath="variables" />
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="variables" ItemsSource="{Binding XPath=*}">
            <TextBox FontSize="25" Foreground="Black" Text="variables"></TextBox>
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
    </Window.Resources>
    .....
    .....
</Window>
```

As well as a save button located in my Grid

```
<StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Left">
    <Button Content="CLICK HERE TO SAVE (not working)"
            HorizontalAlignment="Left"
            Margin="10,10,0,0"
            Click="Button_Click_1"
            />
</StackPanel>
```

My behind code looks as follows

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    XmlDataProvider MyList = (XmlDataProvider)this.FindResource("MyList");
    MyList.Source = new Uri("C:\\CAD.Services\\MASTER.xml");
}

public void Button_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    XmlDataProvider MyList = (XmlDataProvider)this.FindResource("MyList");
    string source = "C:\\CAD.Services\\MASTER.xml";
    MyList.Document.Save(source);

}
```

When I run the program and click the save button, It will tell me that MASTER.xml has been modified outside the source editor, and asks if I want to reload it. However when I do, no changes are made.

I have the xml file set to copy when newer under properties, so I know that is not the problem. As far as I can tell it should work. Any suggestions?

Also if you need any clarifications please ask in the comments, I am new to wpf and am still trying to figure this all out myself.

Comment: Are you looking at the xml file located in `C:\CAD.Services` or the instance that is located in your application's output folder?  You're copying the xml file to your output folder, but it looks like you're trying to load/save a different instance of it in `C:\CAD.Services`

Comment: I would like to both save and load from the `C:\CAD.Services` folder. Where am I putting it in an output folder?

Comment: `I have the xml file set to copy when newer under properties` - I take that you mean that you have included the xml file in your Visual Studio project.  If you have that option selected, that xml file is getting packaged with your project when you built and put in the output folder (you can check your build path in your project Properties to see where this is being built)